# How to combine a query search to show certain defined values at the same time as not showing specific defined values?

Tags: sql, sqlite

The goal is filter out a search result so that the result shows a certain value and filtering out other undesirable values. I'm thinking of a combination between IN and NOT IN? Basically, in the provided example here, the goal is to retrieve the courses that Lennart has taught but not Alan or Kjell.

```
table bb
ccode             course                           name
---------------  ------------------------------  ------------------------------
TIG162           Affarssystem                    Kjell
TIG162           Affarssystem                    Kjell
TIG162           Affarssystem                    Kjell
TIG162           Affarssystem                    Lennart
TIG162           Affarssystem                    Lisen
TIG162           Affarssystem                    Lisen
TIG162           Affarssystem                    Lisen
TIG163           Beslutsstodsystem               Alan
TIG163           Beslutsstodsystem               Faramarz
TIG163           Beslutsstodsystem               Janne
TIG163           Beslutsstodsystem               Lennart
TIG163           Beslutsstodsystem               Alan
TIG163           Beslutsstodsystem               Faramarz
TIG163           Beslutsstodsystem               Lennart
TIG163           Beslutsstodsystem               Faramarz
TIG163           Beslutsstodsystem               Lennart
TIG163           Beslutsstodsystem               Maria
TIG163           Beslutsstodsystem               Lennart
TIG163           Beslutsstodsystem               Maria
TIG163           Beslutsstodsystem               Alan
TIG163           Beslutsstodsystem               Faramarz
TIG163           Beslutsstodsystem               Lennart
TIG067           Examensarbete                   Johan
TIG067           Examensarbete                   Kalle
TIG067           Examensarbete                   Magnus
TIA004           Forandringsledning              Janne
TIA004           Forandringsledning              Kalle
TIG167           Fordjupning i programmering     Dina
TIG167           Fordjupning i programmering     Janne
TIG167           Fordjupning i programmering     Henrik
TIG167           Fordjupning i programmering     Kjell
TIG167           Fordjupning i programmering     Henrik
TIG167           Fordjupning i programmering     Rikard
TIG167           Fordjupning i programmering     Henrik
TIG167           Fordjupning i programmering     Kjell
TIA008           IT - infrastruktur              Aida
TIG065           IT ledning styrning och strate  Kalle
TIG065           IT ledning styrning och strate  Aida
TIG065           IT ledning styrning och strate  Kalle
TIG065           IT ledning styrning och strate  Aida
TIG065           IT ledning styrning och strate  Kalle
TIG065           IT ledning styrning och strate  Aida
TIG165           Informatik som vetenskap        Alan
TIG165           Informatik som vetenskap        Lennart
TIG165           Informatik som vetenskap        William
TIG165           Informatik som vetenskap        Alan
TIG165           Informatik som vetenskap        Lennart
TIG165           Informatik som vetenskap        Lennart
TIG165           Informatik som vetenskap        Marie
TIG165           Informatik som vetenskap        Lennart
TIG165           Informatik som vetenskap        Marie
TIG066           Informatikhistoria och vetensk  Janne
TIG066           Informatikhistoria och vetensk  Janne
TIG066           Informatikhistoria och vetensk  Janne
TIG066           Informatikhistoria och vetensk  Janne
TIG066           Informatikhistoria och vetensk  Janne
TIG015           Informationsteknologi och info  Kalle
TIG015           Informationsteknologi och info  Kalle
TIG015           Informationsteknologi och info  Kalle
TIG015           Informationsteknologi och info  Kalle
TIG015           Informationsteknologi och info  Aida
TIG015           Informationsteknologi och info  Jonas
TIG015           Informationsteknologi och info  Kalle
TIG015           Informationsteknologi och info  Kjell
TIG015           Informationsteknologi och info  Magnus
TIG015           Informationsteknologi och info  Aida
TIG015           Informationsteknologi och info  Jonas
TIG015           Informationsteknologi och info  Kjell
TIG015           Informationsteknologi och info  Lennart
TIG015           Informationsteknologi och info  Maria
TIG015           Informationsteknologi och info  Urban
TIG063           Informationsteknologi och samh  Kjell
TIG063           Informationsteknologi och samh  Kjell
TIG063           Informationsteknologi och samh  Kjell
TIG063           Informationsteknologi och samh  Kjell
TIA015           Innovation och entreprenorskap  Lennart
TIA015           Innovation och entreprenorskap  Marie
TIA010           Innovationsstrategi             Juha
TIG164           Interaktionsdesign              Alan
TIG164           Interaktionsdesign              Juha
TIG164           Interaktionsdesign              Alan
TIG164           Interaktionsdesign              Juha
TIG164           Interaktionsdesign              Alan
TIG164           Interaktionsdesign              Juha
TIG164           Interaktionsdesign              Alan
TIG164           Interaktionsdesign              Alan
TIG061           Manniska datorinteraktion       Henrik
TIG061           Manniska datorinteraktion       Lennart
TIG061           Manniska datorinteraktion       Henrik
TIG061           Manniska datorinteraktion       Lennart
TIA019           Masteruppsats                   Janne
TIA019           Masteruppsats                   Lisen
TIA019           Masteruppsats                   Urban
TIG060           Organisationer och affarssyste  Fredrik
TIG060           Organisationer och affarssyste  Juha
TIG058           Programmeringsteknik och datab  Alan
TIG058           Programmeringsteknik och datab  Janne
TIG058           Programmeringsteknik och datab  Alan
TIG058           Programmeringsteknik och datab  Lennart
TIG058           Programmeringsteknik och datab  Lennart
TIG058           Programmeringsteknik och datab  Alan
TIG059           Systemutvecklingsprojekt        Dina
TIG059           Systemutvecklingsprojekt        Janne
TIG059           Systemutvecklingsprojekt        Dina
TIG059           Systemutvecklingsprojekt        Janne
TIG059           Systemutvecklingsprojekt        Alan
TIG059           Systemutvecklingsprojekt        Janne
TIG059           Systemutvecklingsprojekt        Kalle
TIG059           Systemutvecklingsprojekt        Lennart
TIG059           Systemutvecklingsprojekt        Alan
TIG059           Systemutvecklingsprojekt        Janne
TIG059           Systemutvecklingsprojekt        Kalle
TIG059           Systemutvecklingsprojekt        Lennart
TIG059           Systemutvecklingsprojekt        Alan
TIG059           Systemutvecklingsprojekt        Janne
TIG059           Systemutvecklingsprojekt        Kalle
TIG059           Systemutvecklingsprojekt        Lennart
TIG166           Tillampad IT management         Fredrik
TIG166           Tillampad IT management         Juha
TIG016           Verksamheter och information    Janne
TIG016           Verksamheter och information    Maria
TIG016           Verksamheter och information    Janne
TIG016           Verksamheter och information    Kalle
TIG016           Verksamheter och information    Maria
TIG016           Verksamheter och information    Janne
TIG016           Verksamheter och information    Kalle
TIG016           Verksamheter och information    Janne
TIG016           Verksamheter och information    Kalle
TIA003           Verksamhetsutveckling           Dina
TIA003           Verksamhetsutveckling           Aida
TIA003           Verksamhetsutveckling           Dina
TIA003           Verksamhetsutveckling           Aida
TIA003           Verksamhetsutveckling           Dina
TIA003           Verksamhetsutveckling           Aida
TIA003           Verksamhetsutveckling           Dina
TIA003           Verksamhetsutveckling           Aida
TIG098           eBusiness and eGovernment       Agneta
TIG098           eBusiness and eGovernment       Lisen
```

The retrieved tuples should be:
[image: picture of desired result]

Any suggestions on how the query should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select distinct t.course from tablename t
where name = 'Lennart'
and not exists (select 1 from tablename where course = t.course and name in ('Alan', 'Kjell'));
```

If you want to use `IN`, then this is the simplest way:

```
select distinct course from tablename 
where name = 'Lennart'
and course not in (select course from tablename where name in ('Alan','Kjell'));
```

Comment: This one is quite intuitive language wise

Comment: @MrMiyagi see in my edited answer the proper way for a solution with the operator IN.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select knamn
from t
group by knamn
having sum(namn = 'Lennart') > 0 and
       sum(namn = 'Alan') = 0 and
       sum(namn = 'Kjeli') = 0 ;
```

It might be a wee bit more efficient to filter before aggregation, in which case you can just use:

```
select knamn
from t
where namn in ('Lennart', 'Alan', 'Kjeli')
group by knamn
having min(namn) = max(namn) and min(namn) = 'Lennart';
```

Comment: Second vers, exactly my thought ^^

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using `in` and `not in`

```
select distinct course from table 
where 
   name = 'Lennart'
   and 
   course not in (select course from table where name in ('Alan','Kjeli');
```

Comment: Yep, this one is the most easily understood imo! Was along the lines of my approach :)

Comment: @MrMiyagi . . . This version has several issues.  First, it can return one course multiple times -- you have repeated rows in your data.  Second, `select distinct` in an `in` clause is bad form.  Third, I strongly discourage you from using `not in` with a subquery, because it handles `null` values non-intuitively.  This might not bite you for this query, but it will eventually bite you if you are not in the habit of using `not exists`.

Comment: Although distinct should be used in the main select statement and it is not needed in the subqueries and the 1st IN clause is not really needed it should be just where name = 'Lennart'

Comment: Totally agree with you both @forpas and Gordon. Fixed it

Comment: @GordonLinoff hmm, your third point about 'not in' handling null values non-intuitively seems interesting, I would need an example of this but I'm of course not asking this from you lol! I might indeed encounter it later on, but the tables I'm working with right now do indeed not contain non values so... yeah idk.